# Reusing Control component twice with different values

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a custom Control component that adds an icon to one of my two selections. I need to use the Control component again but to replace the icon with a different one for my second selection but react-select doesn't work if I make a new one called Control2 for example. How would I do this?

```
const Control = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const style = { cursor: 'pointer'};

  return (
    <components.Control {...props}>
      <span style={style}">
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch}/>
      </span>
      {children}
    </components.Control>
  );
};
return (
  <Select 
    options={data}
    components={Control}
    isMulti 
  />

  // I want a new Select with new Control with different fontAwesome icon
  <Select 
    options={data2}
    components={Control}
    isMulti 
  />
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not very clear of the complete implementation here but I think you are looking for  something like this

```
  <Select 
    options={data2}
    components={ () => <Control faSearch="whatevericon">}
    isMulti 
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by checking props for custom parent name and switching icon based off it. Simple solution example:

```
const Control = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const style = { cursor: 'pointer'};
  let wantedIcon = "defaultIcon";
  if(props.selectProps.classNamePreFix == "myControl2") {
    wantedIcon = "differentIcon";
  }
  return (
    <components.Control {...props}>
      <span style={style}">
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={wantedIcon}/>
      </span>
      {children}
    </components.Control>
  );
};
```